# STL collection with multiple values for a single key

Tags: c++, stl

From sql I have a output:

```
id value
123 xxx
124 xxx
124 yyy
125 xxx
```

I handle this output in c++ code where I want to use 123, 125 ids(unique) and  124 which has multiple values separately.

Basically, I want to store unique and multivalue ids separately and later want to retrieve them separately.

I can use any stl container.

say container1 stores unique values

```
123 xxx
125 xxx
```

container2

```
124 xxx
124 yyy
```

In map can I have unique key value pairs: `(123->xxx)`, `(125->xxx)` and `124->xxx,yyy` separately?

Can someone help me to create a better design?

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. I have no idea what you are actually asking. I suspect there's more to what you're trying to do any you haven't actually fully explained it all (just the overview). We can't help if all we have is an overview - please tell us: a) what you expect to see (include example data and example results) b) what you observe instead (include any errors or logs) c) the relevant portions of the code you have tried (even if broken) or at least, some psuedo-code d) any research you have done on the topic. Note: don't answer in comments - edit your question and add it there.

Comment: Improved formatting. Clarified question: it's not really about sql, it doesn't really matter where are these id-value pairs come from. Question is about appropriate collection to use in this case. This question will benefit from code example and specific problem.

Comment: See std::multimap: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be `std::map<int, std::vector<std::string> >` (replace `std::string` with whatever your type is), like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
  std::map< int, std::vector< std::string > > map; // could use std::unordered_map as well for O(1) lookup if order of keys doesn't matter
  map[123].push_back("AAA");
  map[124].push_back("BBB");
  map[124].push_back("CCC");
  map[125].push_back("DDD");
  for(auto itr = map.begin(); itr!=map.end(); itr++) {
      std::cout<<itr->first<<":";
      for(auto vitr = itr->second.begin(); vitr != itr->second.end(); vitr++){
          std::cout<<*vitr<<",";
      }
      std::cout<<std::endl;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
123:AAA,
124:BBB,CCC,
125:DDD,
```

From your description it's a bit unclear if it's acceptable to treat every key, no matter how many entries, as a list of values. But if so, this is the most straightforward way to do it.

Comment: Hi aruisdante, thanks for reply ,,have one query if I can do map[125].push_back("DDD"); operation with map.insert() function

Answer (score 1):

There is already standard support for such a container.

`std::multiset` and `std::multimap` are what you're looking for.

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap